# How are strings escaped for each database extension in php?

Tags: php, database, escaping, sql-injection

*Before anyone jumps to conclusions as to the nature of this question, I already know about [parameterized/prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements#Parameterized_statements) and use them whenever possible. Unfortunately, it is not always possible to use them when building dynamic queries.*

---

I'm interested in working with databases other than MySQL, but I can't easily find good sources as to how to escape strings for each database extension to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection).

The PHP docs list the following vendor specific database extensions. I've boldened the ones I'm most interested in:

- CUBRID
- dBase
- DB++
- FrontBase
- filePro
- Firebird/InterBase
- Informix
- IBM DB2
- Ingres
- MaxDB
- Mongo
- mSQL
- **Mssql**
- **MySQL**
- **Mysqli**
- Mysqlnd
- mysqlnd_ qc
- **OCI8**
- Ovrimos SQL
- Paradox
- **PostgreSQL**
- SQLite
- SQLite3
- Sybase
- tokyo_ tyrant

Example of dynamic query that wont work for most parameterized statements:

```
"Select $col1, $col2 from $table where $col1 = ?"
```

After `$col1`, `$col2`, and `$table` have been escaped, the statement can be used in a prepared statement.

Comment: *One database extension per answer, please. Check existing answers to make sure yours isn't already posted.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## MySQLi

Use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 2):

### PostgreSQL and others (PDO)

PostgreSQL can use [pg_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) for string escaping.

For PostgreSQL you don't need *any* escaping thanks to [`pg_query_params()`](http://php.net/pg_query_params)

Besides that, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) with [prepared](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) [statements](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute). They take care of it and you can pass arguments separately; just like with `pg_query_params()`

Comment: prepared statements are not the issue here. I will update the question with an example that wont work for most parameterized statement systems.

Answer (score 2):

### MongoDB

In MongoDB you do not write SQL but work with objects ("documents") - you don't have to escape things as you never use strings except for data.

However, you *do* need to ensure that you actually pass strings and not arrays to the MongoDB API. At least in PHP passing an array such as `array('$ne' => 1)` would result in an `!= 1` check and thus be similarly dangerous as SQL injection. And unfortunately PHP allows the client to create arrays inside `$_POST` etc. by simply providing a field with a name using the PHP array syntax such as `password[$ne]`. <sup>[[Source]](http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2010/07/mongodb-is-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-in-php-at-least/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## MySQL

Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

## OCI8

As far as I can tell:

```
function oci_escape_string( $str )
{
  return strtr( $str, array( "'" => "''" ) );
}
```

[Should do the trick](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_FAQ#How_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_SQL_queries.3F), ignoring wildcard chars for LIKE statements.

Answer (score 0):

## CUBRID

According to its manual, CUBRID PHP API has the same syntax as MySQL, i.e. [cubrid_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cubrid-real-escape-string.php). With its new CUBRID 8.4.0 release it provides [90% compatibility](http://blog.cubrid.org/news/cubrid-8-4-0-has-arrived-w-x2-faster-database-engine/) with MySQL.