# Updating data using PHP Edit form help needed

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am trying to update my table with the correct information linking to the follwing ID. I will have posted the code so you can all take a look.

Here is my problem: Once i submit the form with all the details recieved from the database, everything works successfull. But when i click submit it re-directs to my other page called update_ac.php. Everything works fine, apart from the data in the mysql tables do not get updated.

I wonder if anyone could take a look at the code to see what they think:much appreciated and feedback would be fantastic. PS I am not the best PHP programmer, still learning!

So here is edit.php - where teh user edits their information:

```
<?php
session_start();
$UserName = $_SESSION['UserName'];
require("checkLoginSession.php");
$adminid = $_GET['id'];

//CONNECTION CODE WAS HERE

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


echo("Logged In As: $UserName");
echo "<br />";
echo("We are editing Data for ID: $adminid");
echo "<br />";
echo "<a href=test.php>Go back to panel</a>";

$id=$_GET['id'];
// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Main Content</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['name']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="mainContent" type="text" id="mainContent" value="<? echo $rows['mainContent']; ?>" size="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?
mysql_close();
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Edit Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Edit Page (<?php echo ("$adminid"); ?>)</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the update_ac.php:

```
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 

$firstName = $_POST["name"];
$mainText = $_POST["mainContent"];

$sql="UPDATE admin SET name='$firstName', mainContent='$mainText' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());;

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='test.php'>Back to panel</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

OK GUYS EDIT HERE:

If in the Update_ac.php if i change the following line to this:

```
$sql="UPDATE admin SET name='$firstName', mainContent='$mainText' WHERE id='1'";
```

The information now gets updated, therefore means something is going wrong with my ID variable

Comment: you haven't defined `$id` in `update_ac.php`. I strongly recommend you read about preventing SQL injection in your code, it's not safe to directly insert variables into a query without somehow escaping it prior.

Comment: ...and after reading about SQL injection, read up on Prepared SQL statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Jonathon, are you sure that the variables in the file update_ac.php are not empty? Are you sure, that data from your form are moved to file update_ac.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the typical omission of database escaping. You need to apply [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on ***any*** string that you concat in your sql query.

The lazy version is:

```
$_POST = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST);
$firstName = $_POST["name"];
$mainText = $_POST["mainContent"];
```

Otherwise you will oftentimes get an invalid syntax error. Use [`print mysql_error();`](http://php.net/mysql_error) after the query to find out what went wrong in your case.

See also [String escaping for each database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939811/how-are-strings-escaped-for-each-database-extension-in-php) or read up on [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) for less fiddly database interaction.

Answer (score 0):

From just a quick glance, it's because you are using variables and not the $_POST variables

```
$sql="UPDATE admin SET name='$firstName', mainContent='$mainText' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Should be the post variables with the names of your form fields

```
$sql="UPDATE admin SET name='$_POST['firstName'], mainContent='$_POST['mainText']' WHERE id='$_POST['id']'";
```

If you then put your $id variable within a hidden input field within your form, that file will also pick it up.

Just a quick answer cos' I'm out to get lunch.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this within my code but does not seem to execute in dreamweaver. Seems to have a error somewhere within the code.

Comment: sorry, I was in a rush. I've just realised you had assigned the $_POST to two variables above the sql, however you would be better off escaping these values. Also as someone else said, you had two ;

Comment: Hi Ashley, yes i did have the two POST variables, can you think of any other fixes? i have used the mysql escape and makes no difference, simply is not updating my database.

Comment: Ashely i have another question seem as tho you are helping me: when i change the line to this:

$sql="UPDATE admin SET name='$firstName', mainContent='$mainText' WHERE id='1'";

The id to 1, the information gets updated straight away..

Answer (score 0):

It is just a syntax error in the update_ac.php

You used 2 semicolons in the following line

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, never noticed it! Unfortunately I am not getting errors when the submit happens, it simply does not update my tables in the SQL, thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: Since the page is empty,I feel that it is only a syntax error.try adding a <title> tag and check if it works.if it doesn't,you can confirm errors in script.I have no idea why the errors are not displayed.

Comment: I have fixed both of the errors but unfortunately still not working, all i need it to do is update the database with the Update sql method